# Replacing Existing Value with new Value in Script Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, configmap

I build a Docker Image and use `COPY xyz.sh /bin/`
The *xyz.sh* file contains 1000+ lines of code and one of the line is **Host:xyz.com**
I used this Image in K8s. Now I want to change the **Host** Value in xyz.sh file.

- I don't want to Create a ConfigMap of full xyz.sh file and replace
  that value with the new host.
- I don't want to create a new Docker Image.

***Question.***

**I there any way to Update only one line or word from ton on lines with the help of configmap or another way?**

Comment: Ideally, you should re-build your image. it also depends upon, where does the code resides and how is the image built (CI/CD), etc.

Comment: This seems like a significant bug in your code that's preventing it from being deployed.  Why don't you want the new Docker image that would result from fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

### Reuse existing container image

A simple solution is using a configmap to alter such `xyz.sh` like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: new-entrypoint
data:
  new_entrypoint.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    sed -i 's/Host:xyz\.com/Host:abc.io/' /path/to/xyz.sh
    exec <your-original-entrypoint.sh> "$@"
```

Then mount this new configmap and use the file `new_entrypoint.sh` in `command` attribute.

This is ugly but you don't need to maintain 1k+ lines of bash script into a configmap.

**Notice**: this may not work if your `xyz.sh` doesn't belong to current user/group that runs your container. Also it violate the idea of *immutable infrastructure*. So you will need to replace the `xyn.sh` via a configmap entry.

### From scratch

So the line `Host:xyz.com` becomes configuration that you want to change at runtime. so you may want to alter such hard coded value into environment variable so that it can be override at runtime.

E.g., in your `xyz.sh`:

```
MY_HOST=${MY_HOST:-"xyz.com"}
```

In dockerfile:

```
ENV MY_HOST="default_host_for_your_docker_image".
```

In k8s pod description, you can do:

```
containers:
  - name: xyz
    image: "your-docker-image-name"
    env:
    - name: MY_HOST
      value: abc.io
```

See [section III. Config of the 12-factor app](https://12factor.net/config):

> Store config in the environment

Comment: @AnkitSingh please edit your question as it has been answered with the original constraints

Comment: @shawmzhu The process you told me is from scratch and I know this way. I can also do to create a ConfigMap and put copy all lines and put in ConfigMap and Update the Host Mount the Path and it will work. **My question is how to insert the new Host value without creating a new Docker Image?**

Comment: Ok, uses configmap to inject configuration into a container works (so that you don't need to create a new docker image). A simpler way is still using a configmap but something like: